# API Gateway forward request to the right endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway and several Lambdas.
I have an app that calls the API Gateway through a Proxy and sends the name of the resource it should call in the header on the request.
Is there a way the API Gateway can figure which lambda to call ? Basically retrieve the name of the resource from the header and forward the request to the right endpoint accordingly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for header-based routing. Unfortunately, at the moment AWS API gateway is **not supporting that**.

I think for solving this, you can use a proxy lambda right after your api-gateway. That lambda can decide your routing since headers are accessible as an event parameter within the lambda function.

Comment: Okay, so this lambda would call all the others depending on the header.
But should I have an SQS or something between this lamnda and the other ones ?

Comment: @Lina, You can directly invoke lambda from another lambda. You can refer this example https://medium.com/tech-carnot/triggering-one-aws-lambda-from-another-using-the-serverless-framework-816006b27b8f